# no logro regresar la diferencia, si alguien sabe hacerlo con filter quedo agradecido

Tags: javascript

Compara dos arreglos y devuelve un nuevo arreglo con los elementos que sólo se encuentran en uno de los dos arreglos dados, pero no en ambos. En otras palabras, devuelve la diferencia simétrica de los dos arreglos.

Nota: Puedes devolver el arreglo con sus elementos en cualquier orden.

Hint 1
["andesite", "grass", "dirt", "pink wool", "dead shrub"], ["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "dead shrub"] debe devolver ["diorite", "pink wool"].

Hint 2
["andesite", "grass", "dirt", "dead shrub"], ["andesite", "grass", "dirt", "dead shrub"] debe devolver [].

Hint 3
diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) debe devolver [4]

```
let diferencia = [];

function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {

   for (let i = 0; i < arr1; i++) {
       let diferencia =[];
       for (let j = 0; j < arr2; j++) {
           if (arr2[j] !== arr1[i]){
               diferencia.push(arr2[j])
           }

           if (arr1[i] !== arr2[j]){
               diferencia.push(arr2[j])
           }


       }
   }


return diferencia

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este ejercicio yo le e visto en una plataforma y lo realize de la siguiente manera:

elabore una funcion que toma como parametro dos arreglos,
utilize programacion funcional, los metodos, concat para concatenar los arreglos y el metodo filter para filtrar elementos.

```
 function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
      return arr1
        .concat(arr2)
        .filter(item => !arr1.includes(item) || !arr2.includes(item));
    }
```

Despues adentro de filtrar lo que se encargara de hacer el codigo es verificar si cada elemento de item (que es el conjunto de elementos de arr1 + arr2) no esta incluido en arreglo1 o arreglo2, si se cumple esto entonces solo tomara los que no se repiten, como resultado se obtendra 4 en el ejemplo.

```
diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

Comment: Me gusta la respuesta, lo único que no se es el costo, que tan costoso es que se revise un item en cada arreglo en cada recorrido del filter. Pero me parece muy optimo el proceso implementado.

Answer (score 0):

Comparto el código que implementé, para los resultados que requieres.

```js
function diffArray(arr1 = [], arr2 = []) {

  /**
   * Verificamos que no se proporcionen valores nulos,
   * si es nulo alguno de los parametros, se inicializa como un arreglo vacio
   **/
  arr1 = arr1 !== null ? arr1 : [];
  arr2 = arr2 !== null ? arr2 : [];

  // Unimos los 2 arreglos
  const fullArray = arr1.concat(arr2);

  // Ordenamos los items del arreglo nuevo
  fullArray.sort();

  // retornamos un arreglo nuevo con los items que no se repiten
  return fullArray.filter((item, i) => item !== fullArray[i + 1] && item !== fullArray[i - 1]);
}

let array1 = ["andesite", "grass", "dirt", "pink wool", "dead shrub"];
let array2 = ["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "dead shrub"];
console.log('array1: ' + array1 + ' array2: ' + array2 + ' resultado: ', diffArray(array1, array2));

array1 = ["andesite", "grass", "dirt", "dead shrub"];
array2 = ["andesite", "grass", "dirt", "dead shrub"];
console.log('array1: ' + array1 + ' array2: ' + array2 + ' resultado: ', diffArray(array1, array2));

array1 = [1, 2, 3, 5];
array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log('array1: ' + array1 + ' array2: ' + array2 + ' resultado: ', diffArray(array1, array2));

array1 = undefined;
array2 = undefined;
console.log('array1: ' + array1 + ' array2: ' + array2 + ' resultado: ', diffArray(array1, array2));

array1 = null;
array2 = null;
console.log('array1: ' + array1 + ' array2: ' + array2 + ' resultado: ', diffArray(array1, array2));

array1 = undefined;
array2 = null;
console.log('array1: ' + array1 + ' array2: ' + array2 + ' resultado: ', diffArray(array1, array2));

array1 = null;
array2 = undefined;
console.log('array1: ' + array1 + ' array2: ' + array2 + ' resultado: ', diffArray(array1, array2));

array1 = ["andesite", "grass", "dirt", "pink wool", "dead shrub"];
array2 = undefined;
console.log('array1: ' + array1 + ' array2: ' + array2 + ' resultado: ', diffArray(array1, array2));

array1 = undefined;
array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log('array1: ' + array1 + ' array2: ' + array2 + ' resultado: ', diffArray(array1, array2));

array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
array2 = null;
console.log('array1: ' + array1 + ' array2: ' + array2 + ' resultado: ', diffArray(array1, array2));

array1 = null;
array2 = ["andesite", "grass", "dirt", "dead shrub"];
console.log('array1: ' + array1 + ' array2: ' + array2 + ' resultado: ', diffArray(array1, array2));
```

Espero te sirva, Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Mira esta forma es de sintaxis más básica, la función devolverArray recibe 2 arreglos de parametros, dentro de ella se genera un arreglo vacio llamado nuevoArreglo.
La función tiene 2 for, el primero recorre el arreglo 1 y en el if pregunta si dentro del arreglo 2 incluye el elemento del primer arreglo si lo incluye lo imprime en la consola , si no lo agrega a nuevoArreglo, el otro for hace lo mismo pero ve los elemento del arreglo 2 si estan en el arreglo 1.
Espero te ayude la clave es usar la función arreglo.include)

```
arreglo1 =["andesite", "grass", "dirt", "pink wool", "dead shrub"];
arreglo2 = ["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "dead shrub"] ;
n1 = [1,2,3,5]
n2= [1,2,3,4,5]

function devolverArray(arr1,arr2){
  let nuevoArreglo = [];
  for(i of arr1){
    if(arr2.includes(i)){
      console.log(i);
    }else{
      nuevoArreglo.push(i)
    }
  }
  for(i of arr2){
    if(arr1.includes(i)){
      console.log(i);
    }else{
      nuevoArreglo.push(i)
    }
  }
  return nuevoArreglo;

}

console.log(devolverArray(n1,n2)) //Devuelve: [4]
console.log(devolverArray(arreglo1,arreglo2)) //Devuelve : ['pink wool', 'diorite']
```